# Prevent Chrome on Mobile to open new email when tapping email address

Tags: html, google-chrome, email, mobile

My web app shows a list with items with certain properties. Each list item is a row, which amongst others an email address. When the row is clicked, it expands and shows more information.

All works fine on the desktop, but on mobile, Chrome recognizes the email addresses and on click it opens the email app to write an email to this address. I didn't set this myself, so this seems to be default behavior.

Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

The code to show the email address:

```
<p class="text-ellipsis"><em>someone@example.com</em></p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up putting the email address in an  tag, then styling this as normal text and disabling the default action through javascript. This way the browser thinks an action is already connected so doesn't do anything when clicked.

Since I was loading the data from a database query into a Django template, any option to add characters in the address itself would've not been possible.

Answer (score 0):

I like to inject "zero-width no-break space" characters to fool helpy mobile browsers

```
<p class="text-ellipsis"><em>someone@example&#8203;.&#8203;com</em></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [chrome://settings/handlers](http://chrome://settings/handlers) then set "Don't allow sites to handle protocols" worked for me.